# Adding and removing a active class to a progress bar based on a click event based on a object's properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this problem for a while now. I need some major guidance. I have a progress bar that is a made up of unordered list `<ul></ul>` with list items inside that make up dividers and circles which are appended to each other like below. They are built based on `StepSize` properties in a object, I loop through the object and assign classes to these list items.

```
<li class="circle"></li>
<li class="divider halfA"></li>
<li class="divider halfB"></li>
<li class="circle"></li>
<li class="divider full"></li>...
```

I have a next and a back button that changes the index, mimicking changing a page in a single page app I have running in another application. The active classes are added only to the index you are on and it checks if you on a specific StepSize for different situations that may arise. For example if you are on the first index and the `StepSize` property is a halfA then you activate circle 1 and divider 1. If its a full `StepSize` instead you active only circle 1. But that is only in the first index situation, after that the logic changes. Hopefully my code will reveal this more accurately than I can in words.

My issues currently are the first and second click or what should be `index=2` and `index=3` do not advance the progress bar or activate the correct list items. Technically after that everything works for the divider active state. I haven't got to fully building the circle active state because I wanted to get the dividers working properly first. There are three StepSize types, full, halfA & halfB (which is two list items but have half the width of a full list item `StepSize`)

I will place my code below, but [here](https://jsbin.com/getipa/edit?js,console,output) is a **JSbin** to play with, and I will also attach a diagram of intended interaction. Also please feel free to adjust the StepSize property to test different orders, but remember a halfA StepSize must always be followed by a halfB.

Hopefully This all makes sense. If clarification is needed I am more than happy to provide them. Really hope this can be solved, I am going a little nutty!

[image: progress bar diagram]

https://jsbin.com/getipa/edit?html,console,output

```js
// Example Object Combination #1 full start -> half end
variation = {
    ActiveSection:'',
    Sections:
        [
          {ID: '1', StepSize:"halfA"}, // Change StepSize's for testing
          {ID: '2', StepSize:'halfB'},
          {ID: '3', StepSize:"full"},
          {ID: '4', StepSize:"halfA"},
          {ID: '5', StepSize:'halfB'},
          {ID: '6', StepSize:"full"},
          {ID: '7', StepSize:"halfA"},
          {ID: '8', StepSize:'halfB'},
          {ID: '9', StepSize:"halfA"},   
          {ID: '10', StepSize:'halfB'},
          {ID: '11', StepSize:"full"}
        ]
};

variation.ActiveSection = variation.Sections[0];

var sectionCount = variation.Sections.length;

// create Progress Bar
var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
progressBar.append('<ul class="unstyled"></ul>');

var content = '';

for(var i=0; i<sectionCount; i++){

    var stepSize = variation.Sections[i].StepSize;
    var stepClass = stepSize == 'full' ? 'full' : stepSize + ' half';


    if(stepSize == 'full' || stepSize == 'halfA'){
        content += '<li><span class="circle"></span></li>';
    }

    content += '<li><span class="divider ' + stepClass +'"></span></li>';

    if(i == sectionCount-1){
        content += '<li><span class="circle"></span></li>';
    }
}

progressBar.find('ul').append(content);


// bind ProgressBar action

var count = 1;

updateProgressBar(1);

$('.next').click(function(){
    var currentIndex = variation.ActiveSection ?     variation.Sections.indexOf(variation.ActiveSection) : 0;
    var nextIndex = currentIndex == variation.Sections.length-1 ? currentIndex : currentIndex+1;
    variation.ActiveSection = variation.Sections[nextIndex];
    updateProgressBar(count);
    count++;
});

$('.previous').click(function(){
  $('.divider').removeClass('active');
  count = count-2;
  updateProgressBar(count);
  count++;
});


function activateLine(n){
    var dividerList = $('.divider');
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        $(dividerList[i]).addClass('active');
    }
}

function activateCircle(n){
    var circleList = $('.circle');
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        $(circleList[i]).addClass('active');
    }
}


function updateProgressBar(index){ 
  
   console.log(variation.ActiveSection.StepSize + "StepSize");
   console.log(index + "index");
  
  for(x=0;x<=variation.Sections.length;x++){
    if(x === 0){
        if(variation.ActiveSection.StepSize == 'halfA'){
            activateLine(1);
        }
    }
    else if(index -1 == x){
      var n = x;
      x++;
      activateLine(n);
    }
  }
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.circle{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:#808080;
  display:block;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:left;
  
}

.circle.active{
  background:#000000;
}

.divider{
  margin-top:10px;
}



.divider.half{
  width:50px;
  height:5px;
  background:#808080;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}

.divider.half.active{
  background:#000;
}

.divider.full{
  width:100px;
  height:5px;
  background:#808080;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  
}

.divider.full.active{
  background:#000;
}

.menu{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<a href="#" class="previous">previous</a>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
```

Comment: Apologies, my original digram was missing a halfA and halfB section it is now added.

Comment: Have you resolved it ??

Comment: changing your `var count = 3;` seems to fix the issue, I was still confused with your code and took time to understand it, But later after sometime of debugging I found changing the value to 3 resolves the UI issue. I still think you need to check the logic variables values

Comment: That works for the current combination of StepSize's however, if it I start to progress bar with a full start it breaks it. My goal is to get it to work in all possible combinations of StepSize's

Comment: Yes understood, But your code was difficult for me to understand, Also to pinpoint where the issue is, It is in your `updateProgressBar` function here inside a for loop you have a `if` and `else if` but there is no `else`  I think you need to checck this part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is indeed in need of some major guidance, even if you have good ideas and you clearly master some essential programming concepts. However, what your code lacks is abstraction.

By abstraction, i mean a lot of things. For example:

- **No `halfA` or `halfB` or `third-of-Z` for that matter**: feeling “a little nutty” is often a sign that you're either too broad or too narrow in your approach. Prioritize abstract numbers linked to a clear scale over monkey-patched systems. Create an array of partial steps that, put together, make whole steps (marked by a bullet). Your example could be thus represented in that matter: `var steps = [0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1];`. That way, you will have a very clear idea of what an “index” represent. E.g. “index `3` in the list above is step `2.5` on a total of `7` steps, so we have 2 bullets active, and the progress bar is half way to the third bullet”. Adding thirds or quarter of steps to this system would be a breeze: just add some `1/3` or `0.25` elements in that list!
- **The least possible quantity of HTML elements**: HTML/CSS/JS can get messy quickly, so let's try to reduce the clutter by removing as many elements as possible to build your progress bar. In your case, a single element by bullet is unavoidable, but you can replace every `<div class="divider>"` by an underlying percent-based progress bar that spans over the whole container on which you can call events like: `$('.progress-bar').width('65%');`. (Bonus: animatable **and** responsive! yay)
- **Namespace and group your logic**: separate the bullet builder, the step change event, the buttons, etc. Make everything modular and use [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) (MDN) to store and manage arbitrary data in your DOM elements. Bind custom events to elements and make them fire each other.

This is an example of how I would solve your problem: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ripahi/).

Comment: good discussion. I might steer the OP towards a canvas implementation, as well, as it seems a little more of a fit for the task at hand.

Comment: Wow! I don't know how to thank you. Abstraction sounds interesting, yes agreed I have understood certain concepts, however there is lots of room to learn. I am going to sit down and spend some more time understanding everything going on in your code, but this is awesome, much appreciated.